# Count if "Yes" Google Sheets condition

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, countif

I have a survey and in this one, there is Yes/No questions I'm counting the answers by questions like in the image above, but I want to make a conditional count like as example if someone from the survey answer yes and there is a conditional question related to that like Are you happy? and there is a mix of answers as example 5 yes and 2 nos gives a total of 7 inputs then the second question if you are happy why are you happy? and from the 5 yes we receive 4 answers I want to count the second question only if the first answers was yes, I have this formulas that make that in a split version:

```
=(COUNTIF(A2:A13,"?*")+COUNT(A2:A13)) # Gives a total of 4
```

Then if this total is bigger than Zero `=IF(H2>0,1,"")` with this for each row I have 1 input as example.

But if one of the first questions was Yes I want to count the second question and this is were I get lost.

I would like to mix the both formulas in just one cell. like this:

```
=IF(Resultofcounts > 0 , 1, "")                   #Resultofcounts= (COUNTIF(A2:A13,"?*")+COUNT(A2:A13))
```

[image]

Comment: You should just be able to combine them how you have them (replacing Resultofcounts with the actual value you listed: `=IF((COUNTIF(A2:A13,"?*")+COUNT(A2:A13))> 0 , 1, "")`. If this is not what you wanted please clarify and I can try to help further

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 I modified with the formula that I'm using and the expected result :   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KOEmeQ4KsA0DzBCEIPjfBLf3J98M62gVa0ssNyB1xHU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 thanks the formula yeah you are correct, now I'm stuck with the conditionals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless I miss something:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:F7="",,1))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX({
 IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B3:E8),,9^9)))="",,1), 
 IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F3:G8),,9^9)))="",,1)})
```

[image]

Comment: I like that but I'm not sure if that works complete with my data base you can see the next question in Sheets2 in the same document. So after question colum f comes the question as it appears in Sheet 2

Comment: Thank you! do you know about email servers?

Comment: I added a second subquestion in the same file in colum H, in that case will be this formula? =INDEX({
 IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B3:E8),,9^9)))="",,1), 
 IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F3:G8),,9^9)))="",,1),
 IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(H3),,9^9)))="",,1)})

Comment: It worked don't have to check but when is empty appears #N/A there is a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Eduardomaker you can wrap it into `IFNA` to hide #N/A errors